# Find CDF of $U^2$ where $U\sim{}\text{Unif}(-1,1)$. How am I misapplying Universality of the Uniform?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

**Note**: This is the same question posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3417896/find-the-cdf-and-pdf-of-u2-is-the-distribution-of-u2-uniform-on-0-1), but I am seeking clarification on how my attempt is incorrect (i.e., where I went wrong).

---

If we let $S\sim{}\text{Unif}(0,1)$, then $U = 2S-1$ and $U^2 = (2S-1)^2$ by *location-scale transformation*. Letting $X = U^2$ we have $X = (2S-1)^2$.

By *universality of the uniform* ($X = F^{-1}(S))$, why isn't $F(x) = \frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{2}$ the CDF of $U^2$? I know this is incorrect because $F(x)$ isn't a valid CDF, but I'm a little turned around as to why this logic doesn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing this [property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_integral_transform) of the uniform distribution, which w.r.t. the present problem reads

- if $F$ is the CDF of some continuous random variable $X=U^2$, then $F(X) = S$ satisfies $S\sim\text{Unif}(0,1)$.

The key point is that the function $F$ must be the CDF of $X=U^2$. In particular, it must satisfy the [properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function#Properties) of a continuous cumulative distribution function. Note that the inverse transformation of $X=(2S-1)^2$ is
$$
\frac{1\pm\sqrt{X}}2 = S\, ,
$$
and that many functions which restriction to $(0,1)$ is $x\mapsto\frac12(1+\sqrt{x})$
aren't continuous CDFs!
The correct CDF is obtained in the [linked post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3417896/418542) as follows:
\begin{aligned}
\Bbb P(U^2\leq x) &= \Bbb P(-\sqrt{x}\leq U\leq \sqrt{x}) \\
&= \dots
\end{aligned}

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, @EditPiAf (...great SO handle, too :). I'm still a little confused re: "...and that many functions which restrictions...". I thought if I inverted $F^{-1}(S)$, that would yield the CDF of X. I understand the solution provided in the other question...I just don't know how to connect this property of the uniform distribution to the correct solution.

Comment: @Per48edjes Inverting brutally $F(S) = (2S+1)^2$ doesn't even give you a function here. Indeed we'd have $F^{-1}(X) = \tfrac12(1\pm\sqrt X)$ which is multi-valued because of $\pm$... The transformation $U\mapsto U^2$ isn't always one-to-one

Answer (score 2):

The *universality of the uniform* tells you that *if* $\ X\ $ has a continuous distribution $\ F\ $, *then* $\ T=F(X)\ $ is uniformly distributed over $\ [0,1]\ $, so when $\ F\ $ is invertible $\ X=F^{-1}(T)\ $.  It does *not* tell you that $\ X=F^{-1}(S)\ $ for any other uniformly distributed random variable $\ S\ $.

In your example, $\ F(x)=\sqrt{x}\ $ so $\ T=\sqrt{X}= |2S-1|\ne S \ $  even though both $\ |2S-1|\ $ and $\ S\ $ are uniformly distributed over $\ [0,1]\ $.